# ITextSharp taking too much time in getting Number of Pages

Tags: performance, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

I have this piece of code:

```
foreach(string pdfFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(selectedFolderMulti_txt.Text,"*.pdf",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //filePath = pdfFile.FullName;
    //string abc = Path.GetFileName(pdfFile);
    try
    {
        //pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filePath);
        pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfFile);
        rownum = pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows.Add();
        pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[0].Value = counter++;
        //pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[1].Value = pdfFile.Name;
        pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[1].Value = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfFile);
        pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[2].Value = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        //pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[3].Value = filePath;
        pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[3].Value = pdfFile;
        //totalpages += pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
    }
    catch
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("There was an error while opening '" + pdfFile.Name + "'", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error while opening '" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfFile) + "'", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Problem is that when today I specified a folder having about 4000 pdf files, It took about 20 minutes to read all files and show me the results. Then, I thought what will this code do when I will input a folder having more than 20,000 files.

If I comment out this line:

```
pdfListMulti_gridview.Rows[rownum].Cells[2].Value = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
```

Then, it seems if all of the processing burden is removed from the code.

So, what I want from you guys is a suggestion for making my approach efficient and less time should be taken to process all files. Or there is any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do what @ChrisBint said, that will get past Window's slowness with folders with many files.

But to get even more speed make sure to use the overload of `PdfReader` that takes a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` object instead. This object is **way** faster than regular streams in all of my testings. The constructor has a couple of overloads but you should mainly concern yourself with `RandomAccessFileOrArray(string filename, bool forceRead)`. The second parameter is whether or not to load the entire file into memory (if I'm understanding the documentation correctly). For very large files this might be a performance hit but on modern machines it shouldn't matter much so I recommend that you pass `true` to this. If you pass `false` the disk will need to be hit several times as the parsing "cursor" walks through the file.

So with all of that you can do this in a very tight loop. For me, 4,000 files containing a total of over 42,000 pages takes about 2 seconds to run.

```
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(workingFolder, "*.pdf");
        int totalPageCount = 0;
        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            totalPageCount += new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(f, true), null).NumberOfPages;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Total Page Count : {0:N0}", totalPageCount));
```

Comment: Same old processing time. I think I will have to stick with this situation. I just added "SearchOption.AllDirectories" in your code.

Comment: @booota, I am very, very surprised. Are you running with at least 1 or 2 GB of RAM? Do you have any really large PDFs, say over 200MB?

Comment: lols. I have C2D processor with 2.5GB RAM. Yeah all the files are about 9GB. A single file is of 15MB max. But it is having a little less time with another folder having 9 GB of files (which are more in number but less in size). 1st folder have approx. 4000 files and the second folder has approx 16000 files. I am also surprised with approx. same time for both folders. I think its the matter of size of a file which effects performance

Comment: It's definitely faster for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would change your code slightly to not call the Directory.EnumerateFiles in the foreach. For example;

```
var listOfFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(selectedFolderMulti_txt.Text,"*.pdf",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(string pdfFile in listOfFiles)
{
//Do something
}
```

I doubt this would impact the overall time by a massive amount, if any.

As far the speed to call the NumberOfPages property. It is unlikely that you will be able to optimise this due to be internal to the pdfReader object. If performance is a concern, then this may require additional hardware.

Personally, I would not factor this as an issue unless I have to continually run the scan (in which case I would start looking at caching/checking for existing files and only adding those that have changed/new).

Comment: Yeah, I think to make performance better, I will be needing additional hardware.